# Problems with env variables on Angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been using an env povider for some time to get environment variable values in index.html, and when using the same method in an angular 13 project started yesterday, I've been getting these validation errors that follow.

```
import { EnvService } from './env.service';

export const EnvServiceFactory = () => {

  const env = new EnvService();

  const browserWindow = window || {};
  const browserWindowEnv = browserWindow['__env'] || {};


  for (const key in browserWindowEnv) {
    if (browserWindowEnv.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      env[key] = window['__env'][key];
    }
  }

  return env;
};

export const EnvServiceProvider = {
  provide: EnvService,
  useFactory: EnvServiceFactory,
  deps: [],
};
```

[image]

**Erro:**
The element implicitly has a type 'any' because the index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> UM APP QUALQUER</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function (window) {
    window.__env = window.__env || {};
    window.__env.apiUrl = "http://localhost:8080";
    window.__env.ambiente = "dev";
    }(this));
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to use (window as any)[] instead. Or set "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true in tsconfig